# How to arrange the image dataset in CNN?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, computer-vision, convolutional-neural-network

How do I arrange the image dataset in CNN? Should I put each image category in a separate folder? Or all of them in the same folder? Should the image name be the category name?

I would like to see an example for an image dataset (other than MNIST).

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directory structure like in dogscats/.(atleast I kept it this way)

```
dogscats

    |-- train

          |-- cats

                |-- catpic0, catpic1, …

          |-- dogs/

                |-- dogpic0, dogpic1, …

    |-- valid

          |-- cats

                |-- catpic0+x, catpic1+x, …

          |-- dogs

                |-- dogpic0+x, dogpic1+x, …

    |-- test

           |-- catpic0+x+y, catpic1+x+y, dogpic0+x+y, dogpic1+x+y
```

*Becareful With the naming of the files also..*

**Also note that you will need a mapping of image names and classes as well like in a CSV or something...**

Also there is no globally accepted directory structure, it completely depends on the API you will use...

**What is a good train/validation/test split?**(depends on your dataset size)

- can do $80/20$ (train/validation)

if you have or are creating a 'test' split, use for (train/validation/test):

- can do $80/15/5$
- can do $70/20/10$
- can do $60/20/20$

Remembering that sole aim is to generalize eventually on test sets...

Comment: How can I map the image name and class in a CSV file? Do you mean create an CSV file and then fill the first column with the image name and the second column with the class name?

Comment: Yes and no both, generally it's provided or you have to make a custom one... With the probability of the former being more...

Comment: If I can recall correctly, I did write such a script here as an answer, you can search a bit or write from scratch

Comment: I want to build the dataset from scratch

Comment: Yes it's possible, there's a GitHub repo here's the link https://github.com/hardikvasa/google-images-download