# Keras: Prediction performance does not match accuracy

Tags: python, keras, cnn, image-classification

I am using Keras/CNN to identify plankton images collected with an in situ camera.  When making confusion matrices on the test sets following training I am finding that the accuracy from the predictions is quite poor.

I have a large number of files and have been using flow_from_directory and generators, I suspect that there might be something happening with the indexing of the predictions (e.g. [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/keras-a-thing-you-should-know-about-keras-if-you-plan-to-train-a-deep-learning-model-on-a-large-fdd63ce66bd2)), but as near as I can tell the indexing of the filenames/labels is matching up.

I worked up a quick example that is similar to what I am doing with the [mnist_png](https://github.com/myleott/mnist_png/blob/master/mnist_png.tar.gz) dataset:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras import backend as K
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

img_width, img_height = 28, 28

train_data_dir = 'S:/mnist_png/training'

num_epochs = 100
batch_size = 128
num_test_samples=10000

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512,activation='linear'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=.3))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(512,activation='linear'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=.3))

model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='Adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# augmentation for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True,
    rotation_range=90,
    validation_split=0.1)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=batch_size,
    epochs=num_epochs)
```

...after 100 epochs I'm getting loss: 0.7517 - acc: 0.7482.

I then evaluate the test set thusly:

```
test_data_dir = 'S:/mnist_png/testing'

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle='False',
    class_mode='categorical')

#Evaluate model on test set
scores = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator,workers=12)
```

...the scores for that were 0.6184 and 0.8168, so in the same ballpark.

But it gets weird when I look at the predictions, e.g.:

```
test_generator.reset()# Necessary to force it to start from beginning
Y_pred = model.predict_generator(test_generator)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=-1)
sum(y_pred==test_generator.classes)/10000
```

The proportion of predictions that are actually correct (calculated in the last line) is around 0.1; when I look at a confusion matrix it's all over the place and the diagonal is a lot of zeros.
I have verified that the test_generator.classes match up with the directories in test_generator.filenames, and shuffle is off.  Per [this post](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3296#issuecomment-349998110) calling test_generator.reset() should force it to take the files in order, but I'm wondering if it is not.

Does anyone have any thoughts on why this is happening or further steps to troubleshoot it?

Comment: I am not sure why the loss is so less, but here is my kernel which achieves .995 on MNIST, Also maybe dense layers needs to be tweaked as directly jumping from 512-->10 doesn't seem a good idea to me! https://www.kaggle.com/adityaecdrid/mnist-with-keras-for-beginners-99457

Comment: Maybe you should verify the directory structure with this https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/34281/35644, Also try visualising the CNN Layers to see why it's so less

Comment: I'm less worried about model performance at this point, the problem is that the predictions of the test set are clearly wrong.  I adapted your model to the mnist_png files and ran it, it worked great, final epoch was loss: 0.0293 - acc: 0.9911.  The test set had good results too (loss: 0.0137 - acc: 0.9952),  but when I checked the accuracy from the results produced by model.predict_generator (i.e. the last blockquote in my original question) the accuracy was 0.09.  I suspect it's the indexing, maybe I'll take this over to the Keras forum.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response, I am also excited to know the Reason behind this, so please do t forget if you figured it out... Had asked few of my friends, they are looking into it!

Comment: Hey After asking them, they say that you should verify your label classes...(high probability that it's messed up) Like class 0 is 1 or something like that, also why a -1 on the axis???

Comment: Also they say why dividing by 10k? WE Need to divide by the #test set images passed on a batch

Comment: Hi:  I divided by 10K because that's how many test images there are.  I found that in a prior example, but don't recall which one or have a link handy.  I also took the -1 on the axis from another example.  It was initially 1, but both seem to give the same results.

Comment: And I have verified that the classes are correct, if I look at test_generator.filenames and test_generator.classes, the classes match up with the directory names.

Comment: But we should avoid -1...( It means auto detection) Maybe works sometimes or it might break sometimes..

Answer (score 2):

Setting `shuffle=false` to `evaluate_generator` and `predict_generator` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thank you, I solved the issue adding shuffle = False to test_generator

Answer (score 1):

It was indeed the indexing,  answer is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/keras-users/bqWwFox_zZs).

Comment: Will keep visiting this post to get things clearer! Thanks Rob

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want something like this:

```
image_generator = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory('test_data_path', target_size=(224, 224), shuffle=False)
true_labels = image_generator.classes
pred_probs = model.predict(image_generator)
preds = pred_probs.argmax(axis=-1)
print (sum(preds[:,0] ==true_labels)/len(true_labels))
```